# Approximate a vector field by a differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, approximation

I have a particular empirical discrete data set observing consumption characteristics of a certain population according to time. Plotted on a graph, it produces a vector field $\mathbb{N}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ which looks like:
[image]

The data set actually has way more points than this, but its general shape is remarkably consistent (with some, but few, discrepancies) and looks like the above image.

I am wondering: this actually looks like the graph of some differential equation, if we ignore the fact the domain of the function is discrete. Is it at all possible to approximate this vector field using a differential equation, i.e., find the differential equation that would best reproduce this vector field (ignoring small discrepancies)? And if so, would anyone have recommendations on where I could start learning how to do this? I might also be very mistaken in believing this is possible or I might be misinterpreting the relevant mathematical concepts, so any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: I guess you can extend your discrete vector fields to a smooth one $V$ , and consider the ODE $x' = V(x)$. What do you mean by "approximate this vector field using a differential equation"?

Comment: @ArcticChar thanks for the comment, I've added a clarification. I meant, the differential equation that would best reproduce this vector field, ignoring the slight inconsistencies in the range of the original vector field. Note that the vector field $V(n_1, n_2)$ graphed above is not a closed form function, only a data set associating coordinate pairs in $\mathbb{N}^2$ to coordinate pairs in $\mathbb{R}^2$ without any guiding analytic expression, i.e., purely by virtue of empirical observation

Comment: Do you have meaningful data?

Comment: @Cesareo hopefully! unless you have a technical definition of meaningful in mind?

Comment: Perhaps  a better definition would be **manageable**...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easily we can obtain a coarse approximation to the field $\{p_k,\vec v_k\}$ by choosing $\{P(p_k),Q(p_k)\} = \vec v_k$ thru a convenient fitting as follows in the attached MATHEMATICA script

```
data = {{852.`, 26.`}, {768.`, 31.`}, {853.`, 36.`}, {763.`, 
 47.`}, {854.`, 55.`}, {764.`, 76.`}, {735.`, 36.`}, {655.`, 
 34.`}, {726.`, 62.`}, {663.`, 75.`}, {727.`, 93.`}, {663.`, 
 135.`}, {621.`, 33.`}, {558.`, 50.`}, {606.`, 93.`}, {541.`, 
 128.`}, {612.`, 168.`}, {540.`, 214.`}, {494.`, 60.`}, {379.`, 
 70.`}, {490.`, 134.`}, {375.`, 137.`}, {481.`, 229.`}, {376.`, 
 218.`}, {324.`, 60.`}, {212.`, 48.`}, {320.`, 124.`}, {212.`, 
 95.`}, {321.`, 203.`}, {219.`, 156.`}, {154.`, 150.`}, {61.`, 
 129.`}, {158.`, 100.`}, {61.`, 83.`}, {160.`, 46.`}, {62.`, 
 40.`}}/855;

vdata = Table[{data[[k]], data[[k + 1]]}, {k, 1, Length[data] - 1, 2}];
datadX = Table[Flatten[{vdata[[k, 1]], (vdata[[k, 2]] - vdata[[k, 1]])[[1]]}], {k,1, Length[vdata]}];
datadY = Table[Flatten[{vdata[[k, 1]], (vdata[[k, 2]] - vdata[[k, 1]])[[2]]}], {k,1, Length[vdata]}];
Pxy = Fit[datadX, {1, x, y, x y, x^2, y^2}, {x, y}];
Qxy = Fit[datadY, {1, x, y, x y, x^2, y^2}, {x, y}];
Pxy0 = Pxy /. {y -> y[x]};
Qxy0 = Qxy /. {y -> y[x]};
sol = NDSolve[{y'[x] == Qxy0/Pxy0, y[0] == 0.09}, y, {x, 0, 1}][[1]];
gr0 = Show[Table[ListLinePlot[vdata[[k]], PlotStyle -> Red], {k, 1, Length[vdata]}], PlotRange -> All]
gr1 = Plot[Evaluate[y[x] /. sol], {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Thick, Blue}];
gr2 = StreamPlot[{-Pxy, -Qxy}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 0.25}];
Show[gr0, gr1, gr2]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 2):

This goes under the name [System identification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_identification). One can apply several kinds data-driven methods to recover the original dynamics.

- [Pop-Sci introduction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NxAn0oglMVw&t=92s) to a sparse system identification model by Steve Brunton
- [Neural Ordinary Differential Equations](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2018/hash/69386f6bb1dfed68692a24c8686939b9-Abstract.html) -  a very general model that can be adapted and extended to all sorts of dynamical systems
- [Matlab toolbox](https://de.mathworks.com/help/ident/gs/about-system-identification.html) if you happen to have a license.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reference! Bounty will be following the minimal award time